# Ĉu estas ĝuste diri "banĉambro" pri ĉambro, kie oni ne baniĝas?

Tags: word-usage

Mi rimarkis ke mi uzas "banĉambro" pri ajna necesejo kiu troviĝas en loĝejo. Do, kie ne nepre estas bankuvo. Ĉu tio malĝustas? Ĉu ĝustas nomi ĉambron kun necesseĝo, pelvo kaj eble ankaŭ duŝo, banĉambro?

Answer (score 9):

Necesejo ne devas esti en banĉambro, ĝi povas havi propran kameron (kiu same nomiĝas *necesejo*). Estas tial nepre evitinde pruntepreni la usonan eŭfemismon "banĉambro", kiam oni fakte celas "necesejo" - oni povus sendiĝi al malsamaj ĉambroj.

Simile kiel en multaj etnaj lingvoj, ankaŭ en Esperanto *banĉambro* estas ajna ĉambro, kiu estas ĉefe destinita por purigi sin. Ne gravas, ĉu por tiu servas bankuvo aŭ duŝejo aŭ simpla pelvo. Tio estas konvencia esprimo, kaj oni ne plu povus paroli, se oni provus anstataŭigi ĉiujn konvenciajn esprimojn per enhave pli trafaj kaj severe ĝustaj.

Answer (score 6):

Laŭ mi, absolute jes! Estas malĝuste diri ke necesejo estas banĉambro. Se iu diras "banĉambro" por "necesejo", temas pri eraro kaŭze de nacilingva influo.

Comment: Cxu vi povus klarigi al kiu demando vi jesas? Mi tiom konfuze metis plurajn en la afisxo.

Comment: Vi pravas. Pardonon. Mi aldonis klarigon.

Answer (score 3):

En restoracioj, gastejoj, ks., kie ĝenerale troviĝas necesejoj, eventuale kun lavaboj, sed ne veraj banejoj, estas eraro uzi por ili la vorton *banejo.*

En multaj landoj (ekz-e Francio) la kutimo ĉe privataj loĝejoj estas, ke necesseĝo troviĝas en malsama ĉambro ol lavpelvo, bankuvo, duŝo, kaj similcelaĵoj. En tiuj landoj ne povas ekzisti konfuzo inter *necesejo* kaj *banejo,* kaj ankaŭ tie estas eraro uzi la saman nomon por ambaŭ. Pravas Kirilo, ke la vorto *banejo* tamen plejofte estas uzata en la larĝa signifo de *personlavejo,* ankaŭ en situacioj, kie persona lavado okazas eĉ sen striktasenca banado.

Tamen, en aliaj landoj temas pri nur unu ĉambro, kie troviĝas ambaŭ instalaĵoj, kaj mi mem observis en Esperantlingvaj loĝejoj la jenajn tri uzadojn (sed bedaŭrinde mi ne povas dokumenti ties relativan oftecon, sendube influatan de etnolingvoj):

- La ĉambro estas sisteme nomata *banejo* (aŭ *banĉambro,* vidu sube)
- La ĉambro estas sisteme nomata *necesejo*
- La ĉambro estas nomata, depende de la intenco, foje *necesejo,* foje *banejo.* (Mi mem apartenas al ĉi lasta skolo: kaj per la vorto *necesejo* mi vere celas ne la tutan ĉambron, sed tiun ĉambroparton, kie troviĝas necesejo. Sed tio jam estas tropedantaĵo...)

La vorto *necesĉambro* apenaŭ ekzistas (2 guglotrafoj). Ne ĉiuj banejoj estas banĉambroj, kaj tio klarigas kial *banejo* estas en Guglo trioble pli ofta ol *banĉambro,* sed multaj uzas la vorton *banejo* ankaŭ por hejmaj banĉambroj, kiel ankaŭ konfirmas tiuj guglotrafoj.

Answer (score 0):

Banĉambro =  Ĉambro por bano, duŝo, korpa purigado kaj flegado. - ReVo

Lavejo = Loko aranĝita por faciligi lavadon. - ReVo

Necesejo = Loko destinita por feki kaj urini; klozeto. - ReVo